# how to include instructions within the enumerate in orgmode latex export?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I can't seem to find this case in the documentation and it doesn't seem to fit the `LATEX_ATTR` options. How can I get orgmode latex export to produce the following (note the setlength statements WITHIN the enumerate block)?

```latex
\begin{enumerate}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}}
\item first
\item second
\item third
\end{enumerate}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this seems to work as you want:

```
* list

#+ATTR_LATEX: :options \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt} \setlength{\parsep}{0pt} \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
1. first

2. second

3. third
```

Make sure there is no empty line between the `#+ATTR_LATEX` line and the first list item.